# Server side socket program not working in PERL

Tags: perl, sockets

I created a simple Socket program in PERL. The Server side program does not seem to complete socket creation. It does not print the statement after Socket creation. The Client whereas waits for message from the Server and then closes the socket. On printing the Socket, It gets the reference of the Server socket but no operation is performed. Please find below the simple Server and Client programs.

Server Side Program:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#tcpserver.pl

use IO::Socket::INET;

my($socket,$client_socket);

my($peeraddress,$peerport);

#Socket creation
$socket  = new IO::Socket::INET(LocalHost=>'127.0.0.1',LocalPort=>'5000',Proto=>'tcp',Listen=>5) or die "Error in Socket Creation: $!n";

print "Server Waiting for client connection on port 5000";

while(1)
{   
    $client_socket = $socket->accept();

    $peer_address = $client_socket->peerhost();

    $peer_port = $client_socket->peerport();

    print "Accepted New Client Connection From : $peer_address $peer_port\n";

    #Send message to the client 

    $data = "Message from Server";

    $client_socket->send($data);

}

$socket->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is likely nothing wrong with your socket creation. Chances are your print statement it being buffered. Either put a new line char at the end of the print statement or set `$|=1;`at the start of the script to force Perl to flush the print the statement without buffering it.

also its good practice to use strict and warnings in your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
$|=1;

my($socket,$client_socket);
my($peeraddress,$peerport);

#Socket creation
$socket  = new IO::Socket::INET(LocalHost=>'127.0.0.1',LocalPort=>'5000',Proto=>'tcp',Listen=>5) or die "Error in Socket Creation: $!n";

print "Server Waiting for client connection on port 5000";

while(1)
{
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();
    my $peer_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $peer_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "Accepted New Client Connection From : $peer_address $peer_port\n";

    #Send message to the client
    my $data = "Message from Server";
    $client_socket->send($data);
}

$socket->close();
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I moved ahead with the force flush resolution you provided.Now my Server is waiting for the client but there seems to be some problem . Plz see my Client program :

Comment: Thanks Chris. I moved ahead with the force flush resolution you provided.Now my Server is waiting for the client but there seems to be some problem . Plz see my Client program :

use strict;
use warning;

use IO::Socket::INET;

$|=1;
my($socket,$client_socket);


#Socket creation
$socket  = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerHost=>'127.0.0.1',PeerPort=>'5000',Proto=>'tcp',Listen=>5) or die "Error in Socket Creation: $!n";

print "Print TCP Connection Success";

#Read Data sent by Server

my $data = <$socket>;

print "Received from Server : $data\n";

$socket->close();

Comment: The output on the Client program execution with the Server waiting for connection is :
Print TCP Connection SuccessUse of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at ClientSocket.pl line 18.
Received from Server :

Comment: To read data on the socket you need to use the sockets `recv` method. So  instead if you want to read the next 1024 bytes of data you should have  `$socket->recv( my $data, 1024);` this would read 1024 bytes from the socket and store it in the `$data` variable.